# C++ specific inheritance example

Tags: c++, inheritance, hierarchy

I'm new to C++ and curious if inheritance would be the right way to go with this example:
The program represents a game, where X players can choose their spaceship with some weapons. The structure of classes would look like this:

WEAPON  ->  SHIP  ->  PLAYER

Weapon represents the base class, where ship is derived from. Player would be derived from ship. Why that way? Because I could create **one** single object for PlayerOne and access all its ship data. Objects of weapon would be created dynamically by a vector.

I know it's a long question, but you could really help me getting started with inheritance.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So each player is a ship and each ship is a weapon.

Comment: but i'm not sure if hierarchy is thought to be used this way

Comment: This should be composition, not inheritance. How would "a player is a ship" make any sense?

Comment: Think it over - is a ship a special kind of a weapon and in turn a player a special kind of a ship in the real world?

Comment: no sense at all, but that's what i'm asking: it is not logical, but I could access every variable through the player-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In object oriented programming, inheritance tends to cover an is-a relationship. A subclass should be a specialization of a superclass.

So when deciding if ship should derive from weapon or player should derive from ship, you need to ask, "Is a ship a weapon?" and "Is a player a ship?". I think the answer to both of these questions is probably no.

Rather, a player has a weapon, or a player has a ship, or a ship has a weapon. Has a relationships are best described by composition; your player class should hold an instance of a weapon (or data structure of weapons) as well as a data structure of ships.

You might want to use inheritance to specialize types of weapons and behaviors. So you could have a Laserbeam class and a Lightsaber class that each derive from Weapon, and each of those would have a different range property.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply! that's all i was asking about

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an appropriate use for inheritance; composition is more appropriate.  A player *has* a ship and the ship *has* a weapon, but a player is not a kind of ship and a ship is not a kind of weapon.

Answer (score -1):

You can use some other alternatives rather than inheritance .which will help you in long run of your code..

Comment: the only alternative is composition, isn't it?

Comment: This isn't constructive or helpful.